# get adrees using json

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-2, reverse-geocoding

Hi i am writing an application which get the current lattitude and longitude and convert it to corresponding address.I am using google maps api v2.Using google api iam able to do this .But sometime i need to restart my device to avoid

> Service not available issue

.
 when googled i found that using json as an option.i am new to json,I had tried some code,  but not getting the address

This is my code using google api

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;


public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap map;
//Location location;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
              LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

              LocationListener mlocListener = new GpsMapLocationActivity(getBaseContext());
              mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

              if (map == null) {
                 map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                             .getMap();  
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
              }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
              // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
              return true;
       }

              private class GpsMapLocationActivity implements LocationListener{
                     Marker marker;
                     Context mcontext;
                     public GpsMapLocationActivity(Context context){
                           super();
                           mcontext=context;
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           if (location != null) {

                                  double latitude=location.getLatitude();
                                  double longitude=location.getLongitude();
                                  LatLng loca=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" +loca,
                                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                  Geocoder geoCoder=new Geocoder(mcontext);
                                  String address="";
                                  try {
                                               List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);

                                               if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                                 for (int index = 0; 
                                                   index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                                                   address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) +  " ";
                                               }
                                  }catch (IOException e) {        
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                  }   
                                  Log.i("Addresss", ""+address);

                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" +address,
                                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       CameraPosition  cmp= new CameraPosition.Builder().target(loca).zoom(14).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
                       map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cmp));

                       if(marker!=null){
                           marker.remove();
                       }

                         marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                       .position(loca)
                       .title("MyMap")
                       .snippet("My Map View")
                       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps)));
                     @Override
                     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                  Bundle extras) {
                     }
              }
}
```

please help me

thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe you have [limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) issue?

Comment: So where is your code using json? I can see only `Geocoder` there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current location using json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238197/get-current-location-using-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Place api for this instead of using Geocoder, refer this-
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Pass your latitude and longitude parameter to this function-

```
private String gettingAddressFromDraggingMarker(double lat, double longitude) 
{
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try 
            {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                    http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng= + lat + "," + longitude + "&sensor=true");
            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) 
                    {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResults.toString();
    }
```

This method returns you string which has address fir that latitude and longitude which you have passed to above finction. Then you can parse that json like this-

```
    try 
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("OK")) 
    {
        JSONArray addressArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject address = addressArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String addressComponents = address.getString("formatted_address");

                    //here you can use this addressComponents string...
            }
     }
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```