# Get current location using json

Tags: android, json, geolocation, google-maps-api-2, reverse-geocoding

Hi i a m writing an application whih gets the current latitude and longitude and convert it to corrsponding address.i can get the lattitude and longitutde but how to convert it to the corresponding address using json. i am new to json. i tried some sample codes butnot getting the address

This is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;



public class GMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap map;


       @Override

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
              LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

              LocationListener locListener = new GpsActivity(getBaseContext());
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);


              if (map == null) {
                     map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                             .getMap();

                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


              }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
              // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
              return true;
       }



              private class GpsActivity implements LocationListener{
                     Marker marker;
                     Context mcontext;
                     public GpsActivity(Context context){
                           super();
                           mcontext=context;
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           if (location != null) {

                                  double latitude=location.getLatitude();

                                  double longitude=location.getLongitude();

                                  LatLng gpslocation=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);


                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" +gpslocation,
                                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

pls help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change back human readable format, you can also use Geocoder but that is not working sometimes because google play service problem. I used this json geocodeing as second option for in case.

Please refer  [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Workflow is pass your latitude and longitude and get current location. Request url gonna be like this.

```
String reqURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat+","+lng +"&sensor=true";
```

Hopefully, this answer will help you.

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(double lat, double lng) {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat+","+lng +"&sensor=true");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}

public static String getCurrentLocationViaJSON(double lat, double lng) {

    JSONObject jsonObj = getLocationInfo(lat, lng);
    Log.i("JSON string =>", jsonObj.toString());

    String currentLocation = "testing";
    String street_address = null;
    String postal_code = null; 

    try {
        String status = jsonObj.getString("status").toString();
        Log.i("status", status);

        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
            JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
            int i = 0;
            Log.i("i", i+ "," + results.length() ); //TODO delete this
            do{

                JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray typesArray = r.getJSONArray("types");
                String types = typesArray.getString(0);

                if(types.equalsIgnoreCase("street_address")){
                    street_address = r.getString("formatted_address").split(",")[0];
                    Log.i("street_address", street_address);
                }else if(types.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")){
                    postal_code = r.getString("formatted_address");
                    Log.i("postal_code", postal_code);
                }

                if(street_address!=null && postal_code!=null){
                    currentLocation = street_address + "," + postal_code;
                    Log.i("Current Location =>", currentLocation); //Delete this
                    i = results.length();
                }

                i++;
            }while(i<results.length());

            Log.i("JSON Geo Locatoin =>", currentLocation);
            return currentLocation;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("testing","Failed to load JSON");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

As my experience, **only device generated latitude and longitude** will work.
Then call

```
String currentLocation = getCurrentLocationViaJSON(lat, lng);
```

Comment: thank u..yeah i tried gecoder i have the same issue some tie i have to restart the device to get the address.i am new to json so it would be very helpful iy you are providing some sample tutorial link or code snippet.Once again thank u for your help..

Comment: This is how to handle json response http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/  Good luck !

Comment: thanks @Megamind it worked for me,will you please clarify what you mean by **only device generated lalitude and longitude** wiil work..

Comment: I mean latitude and longitude which got from locationManager. When I test with custom lat and long which got from Google map, I cannot grab like that format coz json array changes.

Comment: HttpClient was deprecated in API Level 22 and removed in API Level 23.
You can use `HttpURLConnection`:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8655039/4244605