# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-gps

I am trying to build an application where I use `JSON` to get the current `latitude` and `longitude` and also the `address` from it, but as soon as I click on the `button` I get an error in my log:

> E/Volley: [5807] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=0.00.0

The code is given below :

**Gps3Activity.java**

```
    public class Gps3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button display;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps3);

        display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.displayL);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new myLocationlistener();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);

        display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.e("Latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
                Log.e("Longitude", String.valueOf(lng));

                JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat+","+lng +"&sensor=true", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                            //textViewCity.setText(address);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "City : " + address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }

    private class myLocationlistener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lng = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
07-30 01:18:33.287 9750-9750/com.example.shaloin.gps2 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)
07-30 01:18:33.288 9750-9750/com.example.shaloin.gps2 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:293)
07-30 01:18:33.288 9750-9750/com.example.shaloin.gps2 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:521)
07-30 01:18:33.288 9750-9750/com.example.shaloin.gps2 W/System.err:     at com.example.shaloin.gps2.Gps3Activity$1$1.onResponse(Gps3Activity.java:63)
07-30 01:18:33.288 9750-9750/com.example.shaloin.gps2 W/System.err:     at com.example.shaloin.gps2.Gps3Activity$1$1.onResponse(Gps3Activity.java:58)
```

Also I am not able to figure out as to why am I getting the values of `latitude` and `longitude` as `0.0`.

Can anyone help ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the format of `JsonObjectRequest()`. The correct format is given below as suggested by @ZeekHuge

```
JsonObjectRequest(int method,
              String url,
              JSONObject jsonRequest,
              Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
              Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

The correct code is given below :

```
public class Gps3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;
private Button display;
private TextView displayLocation;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private double lat;
private double lng;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps3);

    display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.displayL);
    displayLocation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location1);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new myLocationlistener();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);

    display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            getLocation(lat,lng);

            Log.e("Latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
            Log.e("Longitude", String.valueOf(lng));
            Log.e("city",address);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "City : " + address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            displayLocation.setText("City : "+address);
}
    });
}

private class myLocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitude: "+lat+"\nLongitude: "+lng,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getLocation(lat,lng);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}

public void getLocation(double latitude,double longitude){
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ latitude+","+longitude +"&sensor=true",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                        //textViewCity.setText(address);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "City : " + address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

Although by using this method it takes a lot of time to display the `location`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be 3 problems there :

**First :**

The format of the `JsonObjectRequest()` seems to be completely wrong. The correct format is :

```
JsonObjectRequest(int method,
                  String url,
                  JSONObject jsonRequest,
                  Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) and [this](https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.html)

**Second : You are getting unexpected response from geocode API**

To use google's geocode APIs, you will have to first get yourself the API key.
The format should be something like : (refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) document)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

So you can see there, it needs the API key. You can read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) to get the key. Also **NOTE** that there is a comma (,) between the latitude value and longitude value. Your code is missing that.

**Third : You are getting `lat` and `lng` as 0.0**

That is because the location data takes time to be fetched. The OS do not calls `onLocationChange()` until it has location data with certain precision. So, when you click on the button, you do not have the location updated till then. What you should do is, when user clicks the button, show him a progress bar with message `updating location` and dismiss it only when `onLocationChange()` is called. Use `lat` and `lng` only when 'onLocationChange()' is called at least once.

Comment: I have been following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238197/get-current-location-using-json/20238474#20238474 while making the app, and as you said about the api key , the accepted answer in the post did not have it.

Comment: Choice is upto you, if you wish to go according to a 3 year old ans. where the user might have thought it to be 'implicit', or to believe these [google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), the owner of those APIs

Comment: Okay, so as you said that I missed a coma , I fixed that and now the log shows something like this : `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)`

Comment: I have updated the code and also displayed the `logcat`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: The log shows `index 0 out of range` , does it mean that I have to change the indexing part , I mean do I have to change this line : `String address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");`

Comment: You should manually use that url in the browser and check the output. I think the `resultst` tag must be empty since you do not have the API key.

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=24.7593,92.7839&sensor=true , this is the url with my current latitude and longitude and it shows correct output